# Expo app crashing after splash screen but it's perfectly on expo go development mode

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, eas

I've wasted my 2 days in this problem, Actually I created an expo app and it's running completely fine in expo go app but when I make build (apk) using the command

`eas build -p android --profile preview`

and install it on my phone. It opens but closes automatically after displaying a splash screen. I've tried multiple times so please help. Here is my package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "kotinski-remake",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "lockfileVersion": 3,
  "requires": true,
  "packages": {
    "": {
      "name": "kotinski-remake",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "dependencies": {
        "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
        "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
        "expo": "^49.0.3",
        "expo-barcode-scanner": "~12.5.3",
        "expo-checkbox": "^2.5.0",
        "expo-constants": "~14.4.2",
        "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.3.0",
        "expo-linking": "~5.0.2",
        "expo-location": "~16.1.0",
        "expo-router": "2.0.0",
        "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
        "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
        "firebase": "^10.6.0",
        "moment": "^2.29.4",
        "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
        "react": "18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "18.2.0",
        "react-native": "0.72.6",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
        "react-native-radio-buttons": "^1.0.0",
        "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
        "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
        "react-native-web": "~0.19.6"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.19.3",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.18.9",
        "tailwindcss": "3.3.2"
      }
    },
}
```

I tried everything, in dev mode it didn't have any errors but crashes on the production app.

Comment: Connect your device to system and open the android studio and then try to open your production app and see the error log in android studio

Answer (score 0):

because there's no error code, it could be coming from the code or library, you need to try to build the project starting from minimal code, add the code and library one by one and build, see the prod is crashing or not, you need to keep trying to build and check which library or code is causing the issue.
You can add --local to build it locally if you have mac, so you don't have to wait for expo queue build.

`eas build -p android --profile preview --local`

Check all the configuration you need to do for adding each one of the libraries, I'm suspecting **firebase** and **react-native-gesture-handler** could be the issue.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was `react-native-maps`. My app installed from `.apk` crashed because I haven't provided the Google API key, thinking if it worked in Expo Go it will work everywhere.

And as pointed previously in this discussion, I found the error by commenting out all the code in `App.js` `return` statement, gradually enabling some of the code until I found the source of the problem.